# Information theoretic measures

Tags: information-theory, entropy, actuarial-science, reliability

1. What is the difference between cross entropy and kerridge inaccuracy measures? I will be thankful if anyone kindly elaborate the same.
2. Rao et al. (2004) introduced the concept of cumulative residual entropy (CRE). It has been proved by Di crescenzo et al. that CRE is nothing but the Shannon entropy of the Equilibrium distribution. Along a similar line, Di crescenzo and Longobardi(2009, on cumulative entropies) introduces cumulative past entropy (CPE) as a dual measure of CRE. Now my question is that what does CPE actually represent and what is its interpretation in aspect of the existing measures?